# Search for 4th character on Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, plsql, character, ora-01722

I need to filter my query only to 4th character in a string to 'H' eg:    `CM1H8A6`

I tried `instr(m_reference,' ',1,4)` but it doesn't allow non-numeric values.

> ```
> ORA-01722: invalid number
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> ```

Thanks,
Aruna

Comment: Looks like you're after substr. If I've understood your requirement properly, you're after something like: `where substr(m_reference, 4, 1) = 'H'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `INSTR` function looks for a string inside another string.

```
INSTR(string , substring [, position [, occurrence]])
```

That's why when you call it with `1` as second argument you get this `ORA-01722: invalid number`.

If you're looking for a particular position in a string, use [**`SUBSTR`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm):

```
SUBSTR(string, position [, substring_length])
```

For you this is

```
SUBSTR(m_reference, 4, 1)  -- gives you the 4th char in m_reference
```

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, a solution using regexp_like (3 instances of any character followed by a capital 'H'):

```
SQL> with tbl(m_reference) as (
      select 'CM1H8A6' from dual
    )
    select m_reference
    from tbl
    where regexp_like(m_reference, '.{3}H');

M_REFER
-------
CM1H8A6

SQL>
```